# Get the up vector of the camera in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, camera, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to get the four vectors that make up the boundaries of the frustum in ARKit, and the solution I came up with is as follows:

- Find the field of view angles of the camera
- Then find the direction and up vectors of the camera
- Using these information, find the four vectors using cross products and rotations

This may be a sloppy way of doing it, however it is the best one I got so far.

I am able to get the FOV angles and the direction vector from the `ARCamera.intrinsics` and `ARCamera.transform` properties. However, I don't know how to get the up vector of the camera at this point.

Below is the piece of code I use to find the FOV angles and the direction vector:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
  if xFovDegrees == nil || yFovDegrees == nil {
    let imageResolution = frame.camera.imageResolution
    let intrinsics = frame.camera.intrinsics
    xFovDegrees = 2 * atan(Float(imageResolution.width) / (2 * intrinsics[0,0])) * 180 / Float.pi
    yFovDegrees = 2 * atan(Float(imageResolution.height) / (2 * intrinsics[1,1])) * 180 / Float.pi
  }

  let cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform)
  let cameraDirection = SCNVector3(-1 * cameraTransform.m31,
                                   -1 * cameraTransform.m32,
                                   -1 * cameraTransform.m33)
}
```

I am also open to suggestions for ways to find the the four vectors I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not understood how this line worked:

```
let cameraDirection = SCNVector3(-1 * cameraTransform.m31,
                                 -1 * cameraTransform.m32,
                                 -1 * cameraTransform.m33)
```

This gives the direction vector of the camera because the 3rd row of the transformation matrix gives where the new z-direction of the transformed camera points at. We multiply it by -1 because the default direction of the camera is the negative z-axis.

Considering this information and the fact that the default up vector for a camera is the positive y-axis, the 2nd row of the transformation matrix gives us the up vector of the camera. The following code gives me what I want:

```
let cameraUp = SCNVector3(cameraTransform.m21,
                          cameraTransform.m22,
                          cameraTransform.m23)
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but I'd like to offer an alternative solution (the method and result is different than your answer).

For my purposes, I define the up vector as (0, 1, 0) when the phone is pointing straight up - basically I want the unit vector that is pointing straight out of the top of the phone. ARKit defines the up vector as (0, 1, 0) when the phone is horizontal to the left - so the y-axis is pointing out of the right side of the phone - supposedly because they expect AR apps to prefer horizontal orientation.

`camera.transform` returns the camera's orientation relative to its initial orientation when the AR session started. It is a 4x4 matrix - the first 3x3 of which is the rotation matrix - so when you write `cameraTransform.m21` etc. you are referencing part of the rotation matrix, which is NOT the same as the up vector (however you define it).

So if I define the up vector as the unit y-vector where the y axis is pointing out of the top of the phone, I have to write this as (-1, 0, 0) in ARKit space. Then simply multiplying this vector (slightly modified... see below) by the camera's transform will give me the "up vector" that I'm looking for. Below is an example of using this calculation in a ARSessionDelegate callback.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // the unit y vector is appended with an extra element
    // for multiplying with the 4x4 transform matrix
    let unitYVector = float4(-1, 0, 0, 1)
    let upVectorH = frame.camera.transform * unitYVector
    // drop the 4th element
    let upVector = SCNVector3(upVectorH.x, upVectorH.y, upVectorH.z)
}
```

You can use `let unitYVector = float4(0, 1, 0, 1)` if you are working with ARKit's horizontal orientation.

You can also do the same sort of calculation to get the "direction vector" (pointing out of the front of the phone) by multiplying unit vector (0, 0, 1, 1) by the camera transform.

Comment: This post helped me get the vector that I wanted. Additionally, here's another way I figured out to get the same vector:

`let transformedVectorY = sceneView.pointOfView!.simdWorldTransform * simd_float4(0, 1, 0, 1)`